# Converting []uint8 to float64

Tags: go, type-conversion

What is the best way to handle an http `resp.Body` which is formatted as `[]uint8` and not as JSON?
I would like to convert the bytes into a `float64`.

This is the returned value response:

```
value : %!F([]uint8=[48 46 48 48 49 50 53 53 50 49])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `ParseFloat` from the `strconv` package ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/dIZGnn7a4I)):

```
b := []uint8{48, 46, 48, 48, 49, 50, 53, 53, 50, 49}

f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(b), 64)

if err != nil { 
    // Handle parse error
}

fmt.Printf("%f\n", f) // 0.001255
```